# How can I renew the kube config file expiry date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Today I faced an issue while running my jenkins job. I got this error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command 
"/snap/google-cloud-sdk/234/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /snap/google-cloud-sdk/234/bin/gcloud: 
no such file or directory output= stderr=
```

After when I try to run below command the issue got resolved and jenkins job will complete successfully.

```sh
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster_name --region=region_name
```

Before run this command in my kube config file expiry date was 2022-04-25 and after running above command expiry date get changed to today (2022-05-02) only. Here my doubt if I run my jenkins job on tomorrow (2022-05-03) my job will fail with same error right because of expiry date up to tomorrow only ?

So How can I fix this kube config file expiry date issue permanently not on daily run command?

kube config file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://104.198.97.158
  name: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
    user: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
  name: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
current-context: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_oenofile_us-west1-a_oenofile-dev-cluster
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: ya29.c.b0AXv0zTMYzxRz5DGICZ0wdd1VKT_0qkZFOZ2j69BIEMNNu3p6XDSIyH3T-eO6lJM5JBsB3vmyQ4YeVxTl8_ky3vgRupyJvaFMQRsnu8uf1LiAzC1kuYCsVAwWJNk6Y4RcQOMCue1utIEOjON_z8fO-XxQZiGrzYVIlZUBMzMrOwQn-Aq5XwpcBgqn_iciDL7-Y7IKkZ4F3Q.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /snap/google-cloud-sdk/237/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2022-05-02T11:54:40Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

[screenshot of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0870w.png)

Comment: Can you just run the command to refresh at the start of each job?

Comment: Hi..When job get failed on today at that time i run cluster command only after job get success.Today only one job getting trigger only not others

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be clear: `/snap/google-cloud-sdk/234/bin/gcloud` does not exist.

You appear to be running [`gcloud` as an (Ubuntu) Snap](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-snap). This will benefit from automatic upgrades but, you should not hard code the Snap version (`234`) as this folder will eventually be deleted. I suspect that's what's happened. You should:

**#1** Reference the binary through the `current` folder i.e. `/snap/google-cloud-sdk/current/bin/gcloud`.

However, since you're attempting to authenticate to the cluster using Jenkins, you should consider using a (Google Cloud Platform) Service Account (not a Kubernetes Service Account) rather than your user credentials.

**#2** See Authenticating to the Kubernetes API [within GCP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#service_within) and [external to GCP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#service_in_other_environments).

> **NOTE** It's possible (!?) that you could use [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) to federate credentials of e.g. Azure|AWS to GCP to authenticate to the GKE cluster.